# Is it correct to say "I flexed/tensed my abs muscles when my baby jumped on it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am not sure if it is called "**he flexed his bicep**"

[image]

If a child jumps on my tummy like this, I have to somehow make my tummy hard or else I will get hurt.

[image]

Do we use "**flex**" or "**tense**" to express we want to make our tummies hard? For example,

"**I flexed my abs muscles when my baby jumped on it**"

"**I tensed my abs muscles when my baby jumped on it**"

Answer (score 2):

In that specific case, it would definitely be normal to say "I tensed my stomach", or as you do, "I made my stomach hard" - "flexed" would not make much sense, since the secondary meaning of "flexed" is 'bent', which is the opposite of this case.

For almost all other cases of deliberately using a muscle, it would be more common to say "flexed", though "tensed" would again be technically correct in many of those cases.

Comment: In your examples, it's not clear what 'it' is. Use either _them_ (my muscles) or _jumped on my stomach/tummy_.

Comment: *Tightened* is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

In the example where you're making your bicep as big as possible, "**flex** your bicep" is the most natural.

In the example where a child is jumping on your stomach, "**tense**" or your muscles is the most natural, and "**tighten**" is also good.

To "**tense**" or "**tighten**" a muscle means to engage it, usually *for some mechanical purpose*. If I tense my abs, I might be protecting my stomach from a child jumping on me, or I might be doing a sit-up exercise.

To "**flex** a muscle", on the other hand, usually means to engage the muscle *in order to display it well*. If I flex my abs, the intent is to make my abs look good, like maybe when I'm on the beach or being photographed.

The colloquialism "*to flex (on someone)*" means to show your power to intimidate someone else. It comes directly from this meaning of "flex" for display.